# Merging two dictionaries together whilst adding keys but multiplying values

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, hash-map

I have two dictionaries and a merged dictionary:

```
dict1 = {-3: 0.3, -2: 0.1, 1: 0.8}
dict2 = {0: 0.3, 1: 0.5, -1: 0.7}
dict_merged = {}
```

I have code that basically merges the two together by adding keys together and multiplying values:
e.g.

```
for k1, v1 in dict1.items():
   for k2, v2 in dict2.items():
      new_key = k1 + k2
      if new_key in dict_merged:
          dict_merged[new_key] += v1 * v2
      else:
          dict_merged[new_key] = v1 * v2
```

Is there a faster way to do this, it feels like there should but dict comprehension doesn't seem helpful here. In the above example, we are going to get several contributes to the key "-3" for example.

Comment: Be advised that in Python<3.7 the order of the keys are not guaranteed. Your code might work in your PC, but in someone else's might break horribly.

Comment: @pepoluan strange advice, since the code here doesn't require the dictionaries to be sorted.

Comment: @sanyash What do you mean either 0.09 or 0.07, the code clearly outputs 0.16.

Comment: @Peilonrayz ahh okay I misread the code somehow. My bad.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's standard to indent Python with 4 spaces. Not following this standard only makes your life and the life of people that have to interact with you harder.

You can just use the optional default argument to [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to remove the need for the `if`.

```py
for k1, v1 in dict1.items():
    for k2, v2 in dict2.items():
        key = k1 + k2
        dict_merged[key] = v1 * v2 + dict_merged.get(key, 0)
```

Alternately you can change `dict_merged` to a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), rather than a `dict`. This removes the need to use `dict.get`, and allows you to just us `+=`.
`defaultdict` takes a function that provides the default value to use. Since [`int()` returns `0`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), we can just pass `int` as the function. As noted by [Ilmari Karonen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9012/ilmari-karonen) you can also use `float` as that returns `0.0` without any arguments.

```py
import collections

dict_merged = collections.defaultdict(int)
for k1, v1 in dict1.items():
    for k2, v2 in dict2.items():
        dict_merged[k1 + k2] += v1 * v2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know you could default a get value.

Comment: [`float` with no arguments also returns 0.0](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) and would probably be a more appropriate default factory for the OP, since their actual values all seem to be floats.

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend defaultdict (at least without changing it back into a normal dict), since later on when you actually use it, you'll get 0 instead of a key error when you try to get something that's not there.

Comment: @Noctiphobia I've used `defaultdict` plenty of times, and haven't experienced that issue.

Comment: I agree with @Noctiphobia. defaultdict seem overkill for that problem and can lead to many problems down the line.

Comment: @Peilonrayz You won't necessarily run into this issue, and sometimes it's really the desired behavior (which is the main use case for `defaultdict`), but in this case I see no indication that this is the desired behavior. And while you might not run into this issue (for example you'd never get a key error to begin with), it also may happen. In my experience, that's been a source of bugs in multiple cases.

Comment: @Cal And that's why I provided two alternates...